# How to describe this (paradoxical) motion by the hidden geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity, geometric-series, paradoxes

High-schooler here trying to work through an interesting problem:

> A boy races an ant, giving the latter a head start. The motion of the
> two bodies can be decomposed according to the following steps:
>
> Step #1: The boy runs to the ant's starting point while the ant crawls
> forward.
>
> Step #2: The boy advances to where the ant was at the end of Step #1
> while the ant goes yet further.
>
> Step #3: The boy advances to where the ant was at the end of Step #2
> while the ant goes yet further.
>
> Step #4: The boy advances to where the ant was at the end of Step #3
> while the ant goes yet further.
>
> And so on and so forth.
>
> Given that the boy is running at 8 m/s, the ant is crawling at 0.08
> m/s and the latter has an 80-metre head start, calculate the time
> taken for the boy to overtake the ant.

One may deduce that this lends itself to a geometric series. Since the boy does overtake the ant, the series must be convergent. How do we go about calculating the common ratio *r* and solving the rest of the problem?

Comment: The ant travels at 1/100th of the speed the boy travels. So, if the boy travels over one leg of distance $l$, the next leg will have length $ l(1/100)$. (I would find the total distance traveled, then find the time.)

Comment: This is an example of [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes) of motion.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Hi, this is a little vague. What does the ratio of their speeds have to do with the length of each leg/lap? Could you post a fuller answer?

Comment: You can use this ratio to find, for example, that the second leg has length $(1/100)\cdot 80$, since the boy travels 80 m in the first leg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative velocity (in m/s)  between the boy and the ant is ...
$$v_r = 8 - 0.08 = 8\times \frac{99}{100} $$

So the time for the boy to catch up to the ant is ...
$$T = \frac{80}{v_r}  =\frac{1000}{99}=10.\dot 1\dot0s$$

We can use geometric series to show the the sequence of times converges to the same value.
$$t_1 = \frac{80}8 = 10s$$
at which time the ant has now moved on by $0.8$m

so if $t_2$ represents the time between steps #1 and #2...
$$t_2 = \frac{0.8}8 = 0.1s$$

the common ratio for this sequence is
$$r = \frac{t_2}{t_1}= 0.01$$
The total time can now be calculated using the formula for geometric series...

$$T  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_n= t_1\times \frac 1{1-r}= \frac{10s}{0.99}=  10.\dot 1\dot0s$$

Comment: Ah... I see my misunderstanding now.  The problem has nothing to do with the fact that the boy will eventually overtake the ant from x=vt, given t is sufficiently large. It has everything to do with formalising the motion by considering that (for any finite distance) an infinite number of discrete points are passed, and, by associating an event (the boy catching up) with arrival at each point, this becomes a question of infinite series. This means that we are proving that space and time can both be divided infinitely yet produce a finite result.

Comment: The key is that the absolute value of r is less than 1, as the ant is neither accelerating nor is the boy decelerating.

Comment: Your first two lines of working are difficult to follow, and the solution works without them. Are they alternatives? If that's the case, could you explain why the percentage difference between the boy and ant's velocities is meaningful?

Comment: Hello? Still curious.

Comment: The boy is closing the gap at a rate of 8.00 - 0.08 = 7.92 m/s so it will take 10.10... seconds to completely close the initial gap of 80m

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks

Comment: This means the relative velocity is the velocity of the boy in the rest frame of the ant. If both the boy and ant propagated at the same velocity, the boy would "appear" stationary to the ant (hence, never reducing the separation). Sounds like special relativity. This also happens to be the rate at which the gap is closed, from simple addition of vectors.